# SQL Update a Column From a Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update 1 column (loadStatus) in the Loads table based on if another column (IBLoad) from a joined table is NULL. The end result when running my statement has 0 rows affected. I'm not sure what's wrong here but maybe my WHERE clause is incorrect?

This is the first time I've tried to update from a select so trying to figure it out :)

```
UPDATE Loads SET loadStatus = 'SCHEDULED' 
FROM (
    Select L.OID as [LoadID], T.IBLoad, L.loadStatus
    From [Loads] L left join [Transaction] T on L.OID = T.IBLoad
    Where T.IBLoad is null and load_type = 1 ) i
WHERE  Loads.loadStatus = null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do not need subquery, And use `is null` instead of = null

```
UPDATE L
SET loadStatus = 'SCHEDULED'
    From [Loads] L left join [Transaction] T on L.OID = T.IBLoad
    Where T.IBLoad is null and load_type = 1 
    and  L.loadStatus  is  null
```

or use Loads.loadStatus = ''  for empty string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update from a `select` in this case.  Here is another way to write the query:

```
UPDATE l
    SET loadStatus = 'SCHEDULED' 
FROM Loads l
WHERE l.loadStatus IS NULL AND
      l.load_type = 1 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Transaction] t WHERE l.OID = t.IBLoad);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Gordon - Putting that in SSMS shows incorrect syntax near the Select and also the Where, though. And "The multi-part identifier l.OID could not be bound"